# Why calling this function in the constructor creates stackoverflow error?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Hi I have a `Person` class which has a method `fatherComesFirst` which instantiates a `Person father`. However, when I call this method in the constructor why does the `jvm` throw the `stackoverflow` error? I am beginner. Although I believe so far I am correct.

My Code.

```
package intermediate;

public class Person {

    //getters & setters

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName){
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        fatherComesFirst("",lastName);
    }

    public void fatherComesFirst(String firstName, String lastName){
        Person father = new Person(firstName,lastName);
        System.out.println(father.getFirstName()+" "+father.getLastName());
    }

}
```

Comment: Think about recursion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because whenever you create an instance of the `Person()` class, it calls the function `fatherComesFirst()` which, on the first line of that function, creates another instance of the same class. This is an infinite loop.

Comment: Ahaan, indeed a stupid mistake. By the way how can I do something I have been trying to achieve that whenever a Person object is created an another object gets created as a parent object or with some reference that can link them together? Thanks.

Comment: Look up "factory pattern"

Answer (score 1):

That is essentially an infinite loop. Whenever the constructor is hit, it calls a function that instantiates another Person. When this Person is being instantiated, it also calls the same function that instantiates another Person, which in construction also calls that function...well you get the idea.